# Get relationship node from 2 edges in 1 cypher query

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I need a cypher query that retrieves the weight of two edges at the same time. This is my attempt:

```
MATCH (n:User)-[r:VIEWED|UPDATED]->(f:File) WHERE f.id IN 'some_id','another_id'] RETURN n, r.weight, ORDER BY r.weight DESC
```

The result contains two lines for each user who updated and viewed the file. However, I want the result in one line. For example: user: x - updated: 12 - viewed:15

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED:

try:

```
MATCH (f:File)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:User)-[r1:VIEWED]->(f:File)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (n:User)-[r2:UPDATED]->(f:File)
    where f.id IN ['some_id','another_id']
  return n, 
  sum(r1.weight) as totalViewedWeight, 
  sum(r2.weight) as totalUpdatedWeight
```

Comment: Thank you! The query seems to work but since my files array can be rather big (max 500 files) the performance of this query is rather low. I'm still waiting for it to return results :( 
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Seems like there is an issue in version 2.2 that I'm currently using (https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/4402). However, I have a different problem with that query. 
I created some testNodes. user, viewed: 10, updated: 2, and a file. When I run the query the result is totalViewedWeight: 40, totalUpdatedWeight: 8. Any ideas why? I expect the result to be viewed: 10 and updated: 2.

Comment: Works perfectly and is very fast. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (n:User)-[r:VIEWED|UPDATED]->(f:File) 
WHERE f.id IN ['some_id','another_id'] 
RETURN n, collect(type(r)), collect(r.weight)
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I get the results like this:

user: x - [viewed, viewed, updated] - [7, 7, 4]

Is it also possible to get the sum over all viewed relationships? I'm also interested in how often a user has viewed and updated ANY file and not every single file. In this example I'd like to have a result like this:

user: x - viewed: 14 - update: 4

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: by just reading up the docs for the collect function I guess my reply is almost self explanatory. Full quoting the docs violates the SO netiquette afaik.